# How to fix magento reindexing with PDOException error?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework

I got an error when I reindex data. I have been working for about 3 days with this problem still can't find the solution. here is the log error I have received:

> Default Values (MANAdev) index process unknown error: exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`glasseso_magento`.`m_filter2_value`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_m_filter2_value_mana_db?edit_session` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`edit_session_id`) REFERENCES `m_edit_session` (`id`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCAD)' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Stack trace:

```
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `m_...', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `m_...', Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `m_...', Array)
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('m_filter2_value', Array)
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mana_Filters_Model_Filter2_Value))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Helper/Data.php(217): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Model/Indexer.php(36): Mana_Db_Helper_Data->replicate()
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mana_Db_Model_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}
```

Next exception

> 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`glasseso_magento`.`m_filter2_value`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_m_filter2_value_mana_db?edit_session` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`edit_session_id`) REFERENCES `m_edit_session` (`id`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCAD)' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234

Stack trace:

```
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `m_...', Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `m_...', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `m_...', Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('m_filter2_value', Array)
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mana_Filters_Model_Filter2_Value))
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Helper/Data.php(217): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Model/Indexer.php(36): Mana_Db_Helper_Data->replicate()
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mana_Db_Model_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}
```

Hope that someone can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I took at a look of the contents of m_edit_session, and there was just one line with an ID of 1, and a timestamp under created_at. I changed the ID of that one and only row to 0 (instead of 1) and this error went away.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me! I'm guessing it's because I duplicated the database, as there were other parts which changed the ID from 0 to 1, such as the user management. It's quite annoying that duplicating the database doesn't keep the ID's intact.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution could be to disable "Foreign Key Checks". In file /app/code/local/Mana/Db/Helper/Data.php (217) ...

Change this:

```
$object->save();
```

For this:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$writeConnection->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;");
$object->save();
$writeConnection->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to catch the Exception and log it, so the indexer could finish its work.

Maybe the try{} catch{} Block fits here:

> Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magestore/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Helper/Data.php(217): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()

The cause of the exception may be found in an inconsistent implementation of the Mana-Module.

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistent implementation"?